# How to work with System.Manangement.Automation.Language... ast

Tags: powershell

So I'm trying to create a custom PsAnalyzer rule for the office, and it's my first time using `$ast`  based commands/variables. As a result I'm at a bit of a loss.

I've been using a couple of sites to get my head around the `[System.Management.Automation.Language]` object class, namely [this](https://mathieubuisson.github.io/create-custom-rule-psscriptanalyzer/), [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.language?view=pscore-6.2.0), and [this](https://github.com/MathieuBuisson/PowerShell-DevOps/blob/master/CustomPSScriptAnalyzerRules/MBAnalyzerRules.psm1).

For testing purposes I'm using the function below - dodgy looking params intended.

```
Function IE { 

[cmdletbinding()]

Param( 
    $Url,
    $IEWIDTH  = 550,
    $IeHeight = 450 
)


$IE = new-object -comobject InternetExplorer.Application

$IE.top  = 200 ; $IE.width      = $IEWIDTH ; $IE.height  = $IEHEIGHT
$IE.Left = 100 ; $IE.AddressBar = $FALSE   ; $IE.visible = $TRUE
$IE.navigate( "file:///$Url" )

}
```

Then with the code below, I'd expect `$IEWIDTH` as the only param to fail.

```
Function Measure-PascalCase {
<#
.SYNOPSIS
The variables names should be in PascalCase.
.DESCRIPTION
Variable names should use a consistent capitalization style, i.e. : PascalCase.
.EXAMPLE
Measure-PascalCase -ScriptBlockAst $ScriptBlockAst
.INPUTS
[System.Management.Automation.Language.ScriptBlockAst]
.OUTPUTS
[Microsoft.Windows.PowerShell.ScriptAnalyzer.Generic.DiagnosticRecord[]]
.NOTES
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878270(v=vs.85).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043(v=vs.110).aspx
https://mathieubuisson.github.io/create-custom-rule-psscriptanalyzer/
#>

[CmdletBinding()]
[OutputType([Microsoft.Windows.PowerShell.ScriptAnalyzer.Generic.DiagnosticRecord[]])]
Param
(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $True)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [System.Management.Automation.Language.ScriptBlockAst]
    $ScriptBlockAst
)

Process {

    $Results = @()

    try {
        #region Define predicates to find ASTs.

        [ScriptBlock]$Predicate = {
            Param ([System.Management.Automation.Language.Ast]$Ast)

            [bool]$ReturnValue = $false

            if ( $Ast -is [System.Management.Automation.Language.ParameterAst] ){

                [System.Management.Automation.Language.ParameterAst]$VariableAst = $Ast

                if ( $VariableAst.Left.VariablePath.UserPath -eq 'i' ){
                    $ReturnValue = $false
                } elseif ( $VariableAst.Left.VariablePath.UserPath.Length -eq 3 ){
                    $ReturnValue = $false
                } elseif ($VariableAst.Left.VariablePath.UserPath -cnotmatch '^([A-Z][a-z]+)+$') {
                    $ReturnValue = $True
                }

            }

            return $ReturnValue
        }
        #endregion

        #region Finds ASTs that match the predicates.
        [System.Management.Automation.Language.Ast[]]$Violations = $ScriptBlockAst.FindAll($Predicate, $True)

        If ($Violations.Count -ne 0) {

            Foreach ($Violation in $Violations) {

                $Result = New-Object `
                        -Typename "Microsoft.Windows.PowerShell.ScriptAnalyzer.Generic.DiagnosticRecord" `
                        -ArgumentList "$((Get-Help $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name).Description.Text)",$Violation.Extent,$PSCmdlet.MyInvocation.InvocationName,Information,$Null

                $Results += $Result
            }
        }
        return $Results
        #endregion
    }
    catch {
        $PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError($_)
    }
}
}
Export-ModuleMember -Function Measure-*
```

Instead I get:

```
Line Extent          Message                                                                        
---- ------          -------                                                                        
6 $Url            Variable names should use a consistent capitalization style, i.e. : PascalCase.
7 $IEWIDTH  = 550 Variable names should use a consistent capitalization style, i.e. : PascalCase.
8 $IeHeight = 450 Variable names should use a consistent capitalization style, i.e. : PascalCase.
6 $Url            Variable names should use a consistent capitalization style, i.e. : PascalCase.
7 $IEWIDTH  = 550 Variable names should use a consistent capitalization style, i.e. : PascalCase.
8 $IeHeight = 450 Variable names should use a consistent capitalization style, i.e. : PascalCase.
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? I found another site [here](https://blog.ipswitch.com/how-to-take-advantage-of-powershells-abstract-syntax-tree), if I use that method to test individual variables at a time, I get the results I'd expect to see.

To do that, add the following line at the end of the function IE,

```
[System.Management.Automation.Language.Parser]::ParseInput($MyInvocation.MyCommand.ScriptContents, [ref]$null, [ref]$null)
```

Then this code below will give you length numbers.

```
$stuffast = .\FunctionIe.ps1

$left = $Stuffast.FindAll({$args[0] -is [System.Management.Automation.Language.AssignmentStatementAst]},$true) 

$left[0].Left.Extent.Text.Length

$left[0].Left.VariablePath.UserPath.Length
```

Comment: `AssigmentStatementAst` != `ParameterAst`. `$VariableAst.Left` -> `$VariableAst.Name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike an `AssignmentStatementAst`, which has a `Left` and `Right`(-hand) value property, the  `ParameterAst` has a `Name` and `DefaultValue` property, so you'll want to use `Name` in your predicate block:

```bsh
$predicate = {
    # ...
    if ( $Ast -is [System.Management.Automation.Language.ParameterAst] ) {

        [System.Management.Automation.Language.ParameterAst]$VariableAst = $Ast

        if ( $VariableAst.Name.VariablePath.UserPath -eq 'i' ) {
            $ReturnValue = $false
        }
        elseif ( $VariableAst.Name.VariablePath.UserPath.Length -eq 3 ) {
            $ReturnValue = $false
        }
        elseif ($VariableAst.Name.VariablePath.UserPath -cnotmatch '^([A-Z][a-z]+)+$') {
            $ReturnValue = $True
        }
    }
    # ...
}
```

Alternatively, flip your predicate-logic around to search for `VariableExpressionAst`'s where the parent node is one of `AssignmentStatementAst` or `ParameterAst`:

```bsh
$predicate = {
  param($ast)

  $ValidParents = @(
    [System.Management.Automation.Language.ParameterAst]
    [System.Management.Automation.Language.AssignmentStatementAst]
  )

  if($ast -is [VariableExpressionAst] -and $ValidParents.Where({$ast -is $_}, 'First')){
    [System.Management.Automation.Language.VariableExpressionAst]$variableAst = $ast

    # inspect $variableAst.VariablePath here
  }

  return $false
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for that @Mathias . Worked like a treat. Did you come across this from an online resource or from trial and error? I'm finding this object class is kicking my ass so if you know of any online resources you'd be a great help. Thank you all the same. Has really helped me out

Comment: @GrahamJordan You're welcome! Mostly just trial and error, although I'd strongly encourage use of `Get-Member`, [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.language?view=pscore-6.2.0) and, perhaps [the source code](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/tree/master/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/parser) :)